# units of residuals of a polynomial regression

Tags: r, regression, polynomial

I constructed two models:

```
mdl <- lm(y ~ x)
mdl.res <- mdl$residuals
mdl1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
mdl1.res <- mdl1$residuals
```

Since `mdl1` is a polynomial model, I wanted to know whether the residuals of `mdl1` have the same units as residuals of `mdl`. Are they on the same scale?

Comment: What do you understand a residual to be?

Comment: observed - predicted..so they will be on the scale

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so the question do not stand as unanswered?